# Variable lengths differ with random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm really new to R and I want to make a random forest. However I keep getting the same error-

`Error in model.frame.default, lengths of variables differ.`

I know this issue has been solved in another topic by constructing a formula from strings with `as.` formula but I have really no idea how to do it. Can you help me please? Thank you.

```
#A vector that has random sample of training values (70% & 30% samples)
index = sample(2,nrow(df), replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3)) 

#Training Date 
training = df[index==1,]

#Testing data
testing = df[index==2,]

#Random forest model 
RFM = randomForest(df$Rating~., df$Customer_type, data = training)
```

Comment: you should call it from the data frame, that is `randomForest(Rating~., Customer_type, data = training)`

Comment: yes thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what your error is, is that your independent variable is `Rating` from the `df` dataframe, but you selected `data = training`. This means that your random forest should take data from 2 different dataframes, which isn't possible.
I guess that `randomForest(Rating ~ Customer_type, data = training)` would work.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was really this little thing !